# How to calculate the number of results for different columns. SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

let's say I have a table of dicotomic valued columns "***v(n)***" (n= 1,..n); like this:

```
| v1| vn|
---------
| 1 | 0 |
| 0 | 1 |
| 1 | 0 |
| 1 | 0 |
```

And I want to show the sum of the values for each columns, like this :

```
| v1| vn|
---------
| 3 | 1 |
```

Could someone help me out?
Thanks

Comment: What have you tried?  This is a pretty simple query.

Comment: Hint: `SUM(col)`.

Comment: I am very newbie with SQL, sorry for the easy question. Thanks for help

Comment: @DomenicoBorisSalvati Honestly, even as a newbie, this query is easy and with some effort (search,read docs) should not be a problem even for somebody who has no experience with SQL. Do ask questions, but always do your own research and at least try to solve the problem you are facing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT
SUM(v1) AS v1
,SUM(vn) AS vn
FROM table;
```

As you're not grouping against a field you don't need to include a `GROUP BY` clause.